# float numbers validation in form

Tags: php, floating-point, zend-form, zend-framework2

I am trying to have a form with float number validation. 
when validation works it won't let me click the submit button and will show the proper error message.

I am using zend framework 2 and in my Form I want to retrieve alcohol volume.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$this->add($factory->createElement(array(
            'name' => 'alcohol_vol',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'label' => 'alcohol vol%:',
                    'filters'    => array('Float'),
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'required'   => true,
            ),
    )));
```

this doesn't do anything actually. it will pass validation if i enter regular text.

I also tried changing the type to 'Number' from 'text' but then it won't allow me to use floating number. it will allow only none-float numbers :)

Comment: If the validation hasn't changed much since ZF 1.x, then you need the key `validators`, not `filters`.

Comment: unfortunately adding 'Float' to a validators array didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Float" filter in ZF2, I guess may you want is "Float" Validator, Float Validator could be add into ZF2 form like this:

```
$this->add($factory->createElement(array(
        'name' => 'alcohol_vol',
        'attributes' => array(
                'label' => 'alcohol vol%:',
                'type'  => 'text',
        ),
)));
$factory = new Zend\InputFilter\Factory();

$this->setInputFilter($factory->createInputFilter(array(
    'alcohol_vol' =>     array(
        'name' => 'alcohol_vol',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Float',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)));
```

Then you should validate form in controller, above validators should still set into form. If input not float, the input element will have invalidate messages:

```
$form->setData($userInputData);
if (!$form->isValid()) {
  $inputFilter = $form->getInputFilter();
  $invalids = $inputFilter->getInvalidInput();
  var_dump($invalids);
  // output: 'abc' does not appear to be a float
}
```

Comment: thank you for the information. you allowed me to understand better how to work with validators. the problem is that this does not add javascript checks when the user fill out the form. this adds validations only after the user submitted the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this filter

`new Zend\I18n\Filter\NumberFormat("en_US", NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Zend\I18n\Validator\Float class.  Example usage:

```
$floatInput = new Input('myFloatField');
$floatInput->getValidatorChain()
           ->attach(new \Zend\I18n\Validator\Float());
```

See:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#validating-digits